# Meta tag "viewport" doesn't work on external hosting

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm working on a small project right now, which should also be responsive and work well on mobile browsers. For this I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I purchased the domain http://flaschenbu.ch without any webspace, since I'd like to use a free one. The code above works fine on the actual webspace (which is http://weheri.bplaced.net), but not when I connect this webspace to my domain via A-RECORD and C-NAME. Although I can see it in the source code, it doesn't have any effect on mobile visits.

Does anyone know why? It should be possible to make this work when domain and webspace don't belong to the same provider, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Both the code look same. Hosting doesn't seem to be an issue, as this is gonna be client side.

Comment: I delete my answer and post as a comment: This doesn't have relation. Maybe your server-side code is making differences between that and you paint or not the correct viewport. But The viewport only affects to client device, not depending on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags are not totally related to hosting. since they are not working on server side, they are completely  client side codes.

I think you have to give more information about your situation to find the solutions.

and I checked the code with responsinator:

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fflaschenbu.ch%2F

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fweheri.bplaced.net%2F

they both look same. please check your websites again

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.